# No italics in PDF

Tags: errors, italic

Suddenly, all my text that should be italics is appearing as normal text in my PDF. I've no idea what has caused this issue, so short of posting all my files, I'm unable to include a MWE just now.

Here's some notes that might provide some clues as what has caused all italics to show as normal text in the PDF:

- I'm using the [latextemplates.com thesis template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)
- I'm using XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)
- I'm using biblatex 2015/04/19 v3.0
- I'm using biber
- I'm using Lucida Sans Unicode font
- Bibliography text (including book titles and journal names) that was showing as italics is now showing as normal text.
- all text wrapped in `\textit{}` is showing as normal text
- I'm not getting errors when typesetting
- I'm getting several LaTeX Font Warnings when typesetting, for example `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU1/LucidaSansUnicode(0)/bx/it' undefined`

Comment: Do you have the italic version of the font installed in your system?

Comment: Not sure. How do I check and how do I download?

Answer (score 2):

> `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU1/LucidaSansUnicode(0)/bx/it' undefined`

This means that (as you have seen from the output) that there is no italic font defined.

This occurs because XeLaTeX (using `fontspec`) tries to automatically detect the italic font from the main font choice. When this fails, it can't work magic.

So choose your main font with something like:

```
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans Unicode}[ItalicFont = Lucida Sans Unicode Italic]
```

or:

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont = Lucida Sans Unicode Italic]{Lucida Sans Unicode}
```

(old syntax, will still work fine if you prefer it.)

Comment: Using either of those lines of code cause errors for me, even after downloading Lucida Sans Unicode Italic from here: http://ufonts.com/fonts/lucida-sans-italic.html

Comment: After you downloaded the italic font, did you installed it correctly on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure if I installed correctly, but probably not because it still isn't working. Do you have any links that tell me how to install? I'm on OS X Yosemite, not Ubuntu

Comment: Try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/56295/61375 I don't use OS X